# FFmpeg Error: Output file does not contain any stream

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to use FFmpeg to split an audio file into segments, but I'm encountering the following error:

```
Output file #0 does not contain any stream
```

The code is generated automatically using DDSP-SVC notebook.

```
subprocess.run(f'ffmpeg -i "{filepath}" -f segment -segment_time {sep_duration_final} "{out_filepath}" -y', capture_output=True, shell=True)
```

Here's the command I'm using:

```
ffmpeg -i "preprocess/norm\a.wav" -f segment -segment_time 12 "data/train\audio\a-%04d.wav" -y
```

I have a few questions regarding this issue:

1. What does this error message mean, and why is it occurring?
2. How can I resolve this error and successfully split my audio file into segments?

Any insights or guidance on troubleshooting this FFmpeg error would be greatly appreciated.

I have tried running the FFmpeg command provided in my question to split an audio file into segments.

I expected this command to successfully create a series of segmented audio files in the 'data/train\audio' directory.

However, I encountered the 'Output file #0 does not contain any stream' error, and no output files were generated.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because , as the ffmpeg tag states: Only questions about programmatic use of the FFmpeg libraries, API, or tools are on topic. Questions about interactive use of the command line tool should be asked on https://superuser.com/ or https://video.stackexchange.com/. Please delete this.

Comment: @Rob, I had this issue too, but this issue has appeared from Python Disnake.py, so I don't think that this issue is only interactive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error "Output file #0 does not contain any stream" indicates that FFmpeg doesn't recognize any valid streams (audio, video, etc.) to be written to the output file(s). This can occur due to a variety of reasons, including issues with input file formatting, incorrect command syntax, or inappropriate use of options.

1. **File Path Issues with Backslashes**:

   The first thing I notice is that you're using backslashes (`\`) in your file paths. When using backslashes in a string, they're often interpreted as escape characters, and in your case, `\a` is an ASCII bell character. So, your command is likely not correctly specifying the file path.

   To fix this:

   - If you're on Windows, you should double the backslashes (`\\`) or use forward slashes (`/`).
   - If you're on Linux or macOS, you should use forward slashes (`/`).
2. **FFmpeg Syntax**:

   The order of options and arguments in FFmpeg can matter. For segmenting, the format (`-f segment`) and segment time (`-segment_time 12`) options should come before the output file.

Let's rewrite your command with these considerations:

```bash
ffmpeg -i "preprocess/norm/a.wav" -f segment -segment_time 12 "data/train/audio/a-%04d.wav" -y
```

Or if you're on Windows and want to use double backslashes:

```bash
ffmpeg -i "preprocess\\norm\\a.wav" -f segment -segment_time 12 "data\\train\\audio\\a-%04d.wav" -y
```

Also 2 more comments:

- In Python, consider using a list of arguments for better clarity and security.
- Ensure your input file is valid.

Comment: Thank you so much! It works really well :)